# Angular JS Routing Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Below is my routing defined in html, this is defined in left pane

```
<a href="#loadApp" data-toggle="tab" >loadApp</a>
```

and page content is is right pane:

```
            <div class="right-pane" id="rightPanel" >
                <div ng-view>
                </div>
            </div>
```

when i click on url in left pane right gets refreshed. 
It works fine when i click on it first time, my page gets loaded. but when i click on same url again my ng-view should get loaded again but that's not happening it remains same and nothing refreshes. Is there something that i am missing.

Routing configured as

```
                app.config(['$routeProvider',
                  function($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider.
                      when('/loadApp', {
                    templateUrl: '../html/partials/centralPage.html'//,
                    }).
                    otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/Default'
                    });
                }]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some code samples of your HTML ?

Comment: @VenkatapathiRajuM just edited the code. thanks for checking.

Comment: Probably because you're already at #loadApp the second time you click it.

Comment: @Shomz yes its already loaded how do we handle it in this case, i want it to get refreshed everytime when i click on my left pane

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it without some hacky code (like changing the url to something else, then returning to the original one). What is changing in your view? Is it something that can be updated differently?

Comment: I have a generic app, when clicked on left pane i show some base data on which user do some action which add more component to screen. When i click on url again i want to load the page with base app again.  Will route parms help here  or it will be same scenario?

Comment: i had tried that earlier , jquery was throwing this error and dint help 
  Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/loadApp

Comment: Sounds like you need functions in your view to reset it to default.   As a user, I am not sure I would expect a menu link to default a view.

Comment: its menu link because the app is generic, all the  app will have same link based on parameter different app will be loaded

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an `ng-click` to your top div? It likely isn't refreshing because the page isn't loading, try doing the following:

```
<div class="right-pane" ng-click="pageRefresh()" id="rightPanel" >
       <div ng-view>
       </div>
</div>
```

and in your controller:

```
app.controller('rightPaneCtrl', function() {

var pageRefresh = function() {
    $scope.$apply();
});
```